# How to create RecyclerView with zoom on selected item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

[I want to create a horizontal RecyclerView like this , Please help me with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CubDE.png)

Comment: Please visit the how to ask, before posting your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set LinearLayoutManager HORIZONTAL instead of VERTICAL for horizontal recycleview and increase image scale of selected item

```
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
```